# Add a button on a figure and to close the figure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-uitable

I have a set of data that i have pulled out of the database. I have displayed them in a figure window, but i would like to have a button in which where it closes the figure window or does some other function to it.

This is the code that i have so far :

```
f = figure('Position',[200 200 250 500]); % size of the figure object
dat = listofPdb.Data;
set(f,'name','List of PDBs available','numbertitle','off') %renames the Title Figure
cnames = {'PDB-Codes'};
rnames = {};
t = uitable('Parent',f,'Data',dat,'ColumnName',cnames,... 
            'RowName',rnames,'Position',[100 100 95 350]);
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `CloseRequestFcn` property of the figure:

```
set(f,'CloseRequestFcn', @closereq)
```

where `closereq` is a function what to do when figure is closed.

See [Figure properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html#CloseRequestFcn) for more information and examples.

---

**Update** (after chat in comments):

For a pushbutton you can define the callback function just to close the figure (insert `close(get(hObject,'Parent'))` into `pushbutton1_Callback`) and the CloseRequestFcn will do the rest.

On the other hand, if you want the pushbutton to do something before closing the figure, but don't want to do it with standard closing, then just insert those actions to the pushbutton callback, not to `CloseRequestFcn`.

Comment: It is stating too many input arguments. I have basically copied the code from the example given in the link you posted and called it accordingly to 'closereq'. But how do i wrap this code around a button ?

Comment: Just add code to close the figure to pushbutton callback function. The figure will run `CloseRequestFcn` before it will be actually closed.

Comment: Here is a line you can insert to `pushbutton1_Callback` function to close the figure: `close(get(hObject,'Parent'))`

Comment: On the other hand, if you want the button to do something before closing the figure, but don't want to do it with standard closing, then just put those actions to pushbutton callback, not to `CloseRequestFcn`.

Comment: Another query, how do I allow a button to execute a script? Basically i would like to create a button in which that it states, `'Click the button to continue?'` and it executes a script file that contains other method to do something else ? Is this possible ?

Comment: You can do it, but you will have a problem with **variable scope**. The script will run in the scope of callback function and cannot access variables in MATLAB base workspace. You can pass the variables you need with `handles` parameter, or you can call script with `evalin`, or (the worst) define the variables global. It's actually a large issue, worth a separate question. Try to google or search SO for other similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Type `guide` and design your figure.  Than place a pushbutton over it, right click -> closing function. And define the behaviour you want to have for closing the figure.